# pom.xml <configuration> in VS code doesnt work

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Maven and have a problem with the pom.xml file in my project, it always gives me an error.
The goal, I wanted to achieve with the "configuration" is to connect it with the main branch. Now my question is, how would I do that? I already tried to reference it to the project name.
Note: I couldn't include all the dependencies that I would used as this is too much code for stackoverflow.

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-getting-started</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>
  <name>java-getting-started</name>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <webjars-bootstrap.version>4.1.3</webjars-bootstrap.version>
    <webjars-jquery-ui.version>1.12.1</webjars-jquery-ui.version>
    <webjars-jquery.version>3.3.1-1</webjars-jquery.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build-info</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <additionalProperties>
                <encoding.source>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding.source>
                <encoding.reporting>${project.reporting.outputEncoding}</encoding.reporting>
                <java.source>${maven.compiler.source}</java.source>
                <java.target>${maven.compiler.target}</java.target>
              </additionalProperties>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
<configuration>
 <processTypes>
     <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* .java.GenerationZ/Data</web>
  </processTypes>
</configuration>

</project>
```

Comment: Without the full pom file and even importer the error message? It's impossible to even guess..

Comment: Thats true, I have now added the pom.xml file

Comment: And what is the error ?

Comment: I always get errors at line 114 and 118 with the <configuration>.

Comment: What is this: `<configuration>...`? It's not related to a plugin etc... this looks wrong....remove that first...because I assume that's the line 114...